# How can integral be interpreted as linear model?

Tags: probability, factor-analysis, integral

I've searched how can I apply linear transformation to following problem, but it seems like there's just not intuitive explanation enough for me.

We have
$$
p\left(\mathbf{v}\mid \mathbf{h}\right) = \mathbf{N}\left(\mathbf{v}\mid F\mathbf{h}+\mathbf{c}, \psi\right)
$$

and

$$
p(\mathbf{h}) = \mathcal{N}\left(\mathbf{h}\mid 0, I\right)
$$

resulting in

$$
p\left(\mathbf{v}\right) = \int p\left(\mathbf{v}\mid \mathbf{h}\right)p\left(\mathbf{h}\right)d\mathbf{h} = \mathcal{N}\left(\mathbf{v}\mid \mathbf{c}, FF^T+\psi\right)
$$

I understand the linear transformation of normal distribution, but how am I supposed to apply it for this integral? A lot of material depends on this simple realization, but for me this is not as simple.

Comment: Welcome to CV. As I understand, the question is about how to identify $p(\mathbf{v})$ given in integral form as the  normal density with mean $\mathbf{c}$ and precision matrix $FF^\top + \Psi$. If so, hint: use the closed form for the integrand and "complete the square".

Comment: Thank you for the response! I'm sure if I opened up the integrand and derived enough I would end up with mean $\mathbf{c}$ and covariance $FF^T + \psi$. However, what I would like to understand is, how can I do this easier. I'm told I can use linear transformation $A \mathbf{x} + \mathbf{b}$ where $A$ is some multiplier, $\mathbf{x} \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_1, \Sigma_1)$ and $\mathbf{b} \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_2, \Sigma_2)$ resulting in $\mathcal{N}(A\mu_1 + \mu_2, A\Sigma_1A^T + \Sigma_2)$ I can solve the problem. But I don't know how and what I can plug to $x$ and $b$

Comment: OK then try $\mathbf{v} = \mathbf{u} + F \mathbf{h}$ for some normal $\mathbf{u}$.

Comment: Okay, so I think I'm getting there. If you didn't know anything else besides the information I gave here, would you choose $\mathbf{u} = \mathbf{c}$? In the original statement it is said that $\mathbf{v} = F\mathbf{h} + \mathbf{c} + \mathbf{\epsilon}$ where $\mathbf{\epsilon} \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \psi)$ and $c$ is just a vector of constants. So in this case $\mathbf{u} = \mathbf{c} + \bf{\epsilon} = \mathcal{N}(c, \psi)$? I didn't realize before that I could just fill $\mathbf{u}$ with multiple values....

Comment: In practice we would start from the model form or "representation" $\mathbf{v} = \dots$ This form of model is quite classical because $F \mathbf{h}$ can represent  a regression-like trend.

Comment: Wonderful, thank you! I had confusion also on the previous course where I thought the "model form" wasn't given when it actually was. And realizing this statement solved my question and confusion about many things :)